# Despeckle an RGB array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, rgb

Say so lets say I have an `RGB` array that only has values in the column associated with `Green`.

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          1.          0.]
  [ 0.          1.          0.]]

 [[ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          1.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]]]
```

I want to try to use `from scipy.ndimage import median_filter` to remove all areas that are less than 2 pixels touching.  So I'm looking for the output to be:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          1.          0.]
  [ 0.          1.          0.]]

 [[ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]]]
```

This is just a sample, the array I am working with is much larger 1080 x 1920 x 3 array.  I would I isolated one particular element, either `R`, `G`, or `B` and apply the `median_filter` to that column only?

I have tried this but this does not work as it only outputs the image as a 1080 x 1920 and not the 1080 x 1920 x 3 array:

```
array #as shown above
view = array[:, :, 1]
filtered_array = median_filter(view, size = 2)
```

Comment: I did an edit to show the method I got the closest to working.

Comment: `median_filter(view, size=2, output=view)` may work. If you do not want to modify the original array, make a copy, then run the filter on the slice of the copy.